# How to filter/pipe wmi output from batch or command prompt

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd.exe, wmi

I need to write a little script for a specific HDD.
I use the following command to detect the HDD by size:

```
 C:\>wmic logicaldisk get size,freespace,caption | find "750153363456"

 E:       27996512256  750153363456
```

Now I need to store the drive-letter from that output (in this case E:) into a variable. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

why dont you use the serialnumber to find your drive ?
One possible solution saving the result of wmic in a file :

```
REM replace D4B12CD with your drive serialnumber

wmic logicaldisk get caption,volumeserialnumber |findstr D4B12CD > c:\temp\Hdd.txt 
for /f %%i in (c:\temp\hdd.txt) do set mydrive=%%i

REM now mydrive contains the letter of your drive
echo %mydrive%
```

Comment: I think that if you don't want to do a serialnumber search, you could at least store the value in a text file as demonstrated here.